# Remove non-similar rows in R data frame with all.equal

Tags: r

I want to remove all rows in a data frame where `Month` and `Mo` columns are more than 1 month apart. I have heard you can do this with `all.equal(df$Month, df$Mo, 1)`, but it is just returning a string. Is this possible in R?

```
Row Month Mo
1   1     1
1   2     4 #<-Remove
```

Comment: Can you add some test data to the question? What's in the Month and Mo columns?

Comment: They are numeric columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?all.equal` documentation, the return value of `all.equal` is

> Either TRUE (NULL for attr.all.equal) or a vector of mode "character" describing the differences between target and current.

So no, you can't do it with `all.equal`, as it returns a single value. You can see more details in the docs about what the function does.

To do what you want, you can use plain R:

```
d <- data.frame(Row = 1:2, Month = 1:2, Mo = c(1,4)) # your data.frame
#   Row Month Mo
# 1   1     1  1
# 2   2     2  4

d[!(abs(d$Month - d$Mo) > 1),] # d without rows where Month and Mo are far apart.
#   Row Month Mo
# 1   1     1  1
```

or equivalently

```
d[abs(d$Month - d$Mo) <= 1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    filter(Month == Mo | Month == Mo+1 | Month == Mo-1)
```